# Windows 8.1-Black screen Coming before Login Page

Tags: windows-8.1

Recently I upgraded to windows 8.1 from windows 8 successfully. But Windows boot time is taking longer than usual. Everytime when I poweron my laptop, windows logo is coming for few seconds and black screen is coming (without mouse pointer) for another couple of minutes. then login page is coming. Then I can login in to my laptop, no problem after.

My question is why is the black screen coming between windows logo and login page for few mins. I couldnt face this issue when I was in Windows 8.

I tried clean boot also, it doesn't work.

Any help or fix would be appreciated.

Comment: capture a boot trace: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=158252 and share the trace (SkyDrive, dropbox).

Answer (score 0):

I know I have had a similar issue with Windows 7. I'm not sure if it applies here but check to see if you have network drives that may not be able to connect immediately. I had some network drives to my HTPC set to connect to my Windows 7 desktop at boot that caused an obnoxiously long lagg with just a black screen and a curser after login. This was because my HTPC was not always running when it booted, and since the drive was set to connect, Windows would freak out and lagg.

It took me a long time to figure out that it was the network drives. (I know that this sounds completely weird...) To test, you will need to delete the network drives from your Windows 8 computer so they don't connect at start-up. If this does, perhaps you can create a script to connect the drives on delay.